# Wix Project Installer Version Issue

Tags: wix, cicd, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, excel-addins

We have a old wix project which creates a installer (excel add in) which has been moved to use yaml pipeline but now the installer is getting created in the folder 1.0.0.0 instead of the next version

I have been struggling to understand from where is it been driven as I cannot find anything from the repository.

I have also made a small edit on the powershell script which I thought was responsible but it had no effect

```
- powershell: |
          $versions = [xml](Get-Content '$(PublishLocation)\version_info.xml')
          $lastChild = $versions.application.product.LastChild
          $versions.application.product.RemoveChild($lastChild)
          $latest_version = $versions.application.product.LastChild.name
          
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MSIVersion;]$latest_version"
          Write-Host "Set MSIVersion variable to ($latest_version)"
        displayName: 'Parse installed MSI version'
```

I added the remove last child bit and I see the right version but still the installer goes and sits in the 1.0.0.0 folder

I am also confused about the version_info xml which is being read, I do not see it in the solution. A web.config however has the following entry:

```
<add wildcard="/devxls/version_info.xml" destination="/excel-add-in/version_info.xml" />
```

So basically I need the new folder which is getting created to have the correction version number as its name and the new installer to get created inside that.

Please let me know if some other information is also required as I have never worked on this type of project so it is fairly new to me.

Edit 1:
Yaml build and release

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName:
    pool:
      name: 
    steps:
    - checkout: self

    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 5.7.0

    - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'NuGet restore'
      inputs:
        vstsFeed: ''

    - task: SonarSource.sonarqube.15B84CA1-B62F-4A2A-A403-89B77A063157.SonarQubePrepare@4
      inputs:
        SonarQube: 
        projectKey: ''
        projectName: ''
      continueOnError: true

    - task: colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-buildtasks.version-assemblies-task.VersionAssemblies@2
      displayName: 'Version Assemblies'
      inputs:
        sourcePath: (solution name)
        versionFormat: threeParts
        replaceVersionFormat: threeParts

    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build WIX Project'
      inputs:
        solution: wixproject path
        msbuildArgs: ''
        configuration: ''
        clean: true

    - task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
      inputs:
        versionSelector: latestStable

    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: ''
      inputs:
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          
          testFiltercriteria: ''
          vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller

    - task: SonarSource.sonarqube.6D01813A-9589-4B15-8491-8164AEB38055.SonarQubeAnalyze@4
      displayName: 'Run Code Analysis'
      continueOnError: true

    - task: SonarSource.sonarqube.291ed61f-1ee4-45d3-b1b0-bf822d9095ef.SonarQubePublish@4
      displayName: 'Publish Quality Gate Result'
      continueOnError: true

    - task: PublishSymbols@2
      displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
      inputs:
        SymbolServerType: TeamServices

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.StagingDirectory)\drop'
      inputs:
        Contents: |
          
        
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)\drop'
        CleanTargetFolder: true
        flattenFolders: true

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)\drop'

- template: ./env.yml
  parameters:
    env: 
    dependsOn: Build    
    //other parameters
```

env.yml

```
parameters:
- name: env
  type: string
  

stages:
- stage: 
  dependsOn: 
  condition: 
  displayName: 
  variables:   
    
  
  pool:
    name: 
  jobs:
  - deployment: InstallIIS
    displayName: 
    pool:
      name: 
    environment: 
      name: 
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - checkout:
              path: ''

            - task: PowerShell@2
              inputs:
                targetType: filePath
                filePath: ''
                arguments: ''

            - task: PowerShell@2
              inputs:
                targetType: filePath
                filePath: 'powershell script path'
                arguments: ''

            - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
              displayName: 'Manage Root'
              inputs:
                EnableIIS: true
                WebsiteName: ''
                WebsitePhysicalPath: ''
                WebsitePhysicalPathAuth: WebsiteWindowsAuth
                WebsiteAuthUserName: ''
                WebsiteAuthUserPassword: 
                AddBinding: true
                Bindings: ''
                CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite: true
                ConfigureAuthenticationForWebsite: true
                AppPoolNameForWebsite: ''
                AnonymousAuthenticationForWebsite: true
                WindowsAuthenticationForWebsite: false

            - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
              displayName: 'Manage App'
              inputs:
                EnableIIS: true
                IISDeploymentType: IISWebApplication
                ParentWebsiteNameForApplication: ''
                VirtualPathForApplication: ''
                PhysicalPathForApplication: ''
                ApplicationPhysicalPathAuth: ApplicationWindowsAuth
                ApplicationAuthUserName: ''
                ApplicationAuthUserPassword: ''
                CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForApplication: true
                AppPoolNameForApplication: ''

  - job: InstallMSI
    dependsOn: InstallIIS
    displayName: Install MSI
    steps:
      - download: current
        artifact: drop
              
      - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
        displayName: 'Replace tokens in adxpublisher.config'
        inputs:
          rootDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'
          targetFiles: adxpublisher.config
          actionOnMissing: fail
          tokenPrefix: '__'
          tokenSuffix: '__'

      - script: '"$(adx.path)\Adxpublisher.exe" /OutputType=ClickTwice /ConfigFile=./adxpublisher.config'
        workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'
        failOnStderr: true
        displayName: 'Deploy MSI'

      - powershell: |
          $versions = [xml](Get-Content '$(PublishLocation)\version_info.xml')
          $lastChild = $versions.application.product.LastChild
          $versions.application.product.RemoveChild($lastChild)
          $latest_version = $versions.application.product.LastChild.name
          
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MSIVersion;]$latest_version"
          Write-Host "Set MSIVersion variable to ($latest_version)"
        displayName: 'Parse installed MSI version'

      - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
        displayName: 'Replace tokens in web.config'
        inputs:
          rootDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'
          targetFiles: web.config
          actionOnMissing: fail
          tokenPrefix: '__'
          tokenSuffix: '__'

      - task: CopyFiles@2
        displayName: 'Copy web.config'
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'
          Contents: web.config
          TargetFolder: '$(PublishLocationRoot)'
          OverWrite: true
```

Edit 2:

[image]

Comment: Before you moved to use YAML pipeline to generate the installer, how did you generate the installer in the past? What tools and commands/scripts did you use to generate the installer in the past?

Comment: Also share the complete YAML of your YAML pipeline.

Comment: It was using classic pipeline

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT I have added the yaml files

Comment: What is the definition of your classic pipeline?

Comment: I am sorry can you please tell me what do you mean by definition of classic pipeline? However my guess is it has something to do with wix project set up or configuration it uses. However I am still unable to understand exactly what it is

Comment: You can export the definition of classic pipeline as a YAML/JSON file. Then you can compare the definition with your YAML pipeline to see whether there are any different configurations between them that may cause the YAML pipeline cannot work.

Comment: Yes it is the same

Comment: I am trying to build the project I have installed 4.5 framework and wix toolset for vs 2022. However I am seeing lot of The type or namespace name 'AddinExpress' could not be found (missing directive or assembly reference) and I see under references for one project System.Web.Helpers has a yellow triangle and another project AddinExpress.MSO.2005 reference has the same

Comment: I think I see something adding an image to the question: Version assembly task is not having the same logs as in classic vs yaml. There is one more param not showing in snap it is called source path which is set to the solution name